# Asp MVC Convert ToDouble and InvariantCulture

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

In asp mvc I have an input text control that must accept a double number.

I have customized the jQuery validation plugin to accept number with `.` and `,` separator and written a custom `DecimalBinder`:

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        object actualValue = null;
        try
        {
            actualValue = Convert.ToDouble(valueResult.AttemptedValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            modelState.Errors.Add(e);
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

The problem is that if in the input text control I write, for example, "3,3" the

```
actualValue = Convert.ToDouble(valueResult.AttemptedValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

give me the value "33" and, instead, I want 3.3.

When I inspect the `modelState` I see

[image]

**Why actualValue is "33" instead of "3.3" if i use `InvariantCulture`?**

Comment: Because the invariant culture uses `.` as decimal separator, not `,`.

Comment: I suggest you, to have exact prefefined culture. For example if you will use `it-IT`, then just replace comma with dot and then parse.

Answer (score 2):

That is because `3,3` converted to a double using the `InvariantCulture` yields `33`. It does not make the output to become in the `InvariantCulture`, since the numeric data type double has nothing to do with a specific culture. Only the *textual representation* does.

So `3,3` is not a valid value for a string to be converted to a double. It removes the `,` and converts to `33`. `3.3` would be a valid value to be converted to `3.3d`. So you have to use another culture, probably `it-IT` as in your debug view, to convert the value `3,3` to a `double` of `3.3d`.

Comment: Needs more inline code markup.

Comment: That is very true. I first had less, but that become quite inconsistent. And consistency is important, right? ;) Removed some.